# How to select different value from same column?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a `table` which has 2 `column`, Type and Age, but I want to display in 5 column due to it's condition like this example:
|  TYPE  | Age < 10 | 10<=Age<20 | Age > 20 |

How can I achieve this since it has only 2 `column`?

I've try selecting same table with different alias, but it was not good, long in execution time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

Use [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) statement

```
select TYPE,
       case when  Age < 10 then age end as ' Age<10',
       case when  Age between 10 and 20  then age end as ' Age 10-20',
       case when  Age > 20 then age end as ' Age>20'  
from
your_table
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you save my day. But there is one weakness when I try it, it cost much memory.

Answer (score 2):

What do you want as the column values? A boolean?

```
SELECT type, 
  age < 10               AS "Age < 10", 
  age >= 10 AND age < 20 AS "10 <= Age < 20", 
  age > 20               AS "Age > 20" 
FROM table_name;
```

Ok, so apparently you want the aggregate (count of number in each age group)

```
SELECT type,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name AS t2 WHERE age < 10 AND t2.type = type) AS "Age < 10",
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name AS t2 WHERE age >= 10 AND age < 20 AND t2.type = type) AS "10 <= Age < 20)"
  ...and so on...
FROM table_name
```

I guess that is the same as the solution you thought was too slow? I cannot think of another better one. Conditional indexes on age would help but MySQL does not support conditional indexes. In PostgreSQL you could `CREATE INDEX ON table_name (age) WHERE age < 10 ...`

Comment: So, "how many type has age < 10" means you want an aggregate function then...neither of the current answers will work.

Comment: how many what? in this case I just want to display 3 different condition. when I try your answer it says "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"